# How do you transfer weight paint in blender 2.8

Tags: weight-painting

How do you transfer weight paint in blender 2.8? I want to transfer the weight paint of my character to my clothes?

Answer (score 2):

As of the stable release of 2.80, Transfer Weight option is consolidated into Transfer Mesh Data, and now located under Object > Relations > Transfer Mesh Data. This option is already available in Object Mode, no need to enter Weight Mode and accidentally paint a weight data in the process.

However, the selection order for the Transfer Weight is somehow reversed. So, instead of transferring weight from the **first selection** to **second selection**, it's actually ***vice versa*** in 2.80 - the tool transfers weight from the **second selection** to the **first selection**.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I know this is late but it still might be helpful to others :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Transfer Modifier on your clothes mesh and select Vertex Data, Projected Face Interpolated (experiment here), Vertex Groups, All Layers > By Name.

Comment: Data Transfer Modifier does not work fine in 2.8. Only old metod in 2.79 works correct